# Force strict sql mode in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to force my django project to always use strict `sql_mode`. Is there another way than putting the following in `manage.py`? It seems overly complicated.

```
def set_strict_sql_mode(sender, **kwargs):
    from django.conf import settings
    if settings.DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] == 'django.db.backends.mysql':
        from django.db import connection
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SET session sql_mode=traditional')

from django.core.signals import request_started
request_started.connect(set_strict_sql_mode)
```

Comment: Don't hate me for this, since initialization code for django was never resolved in a clean way: Have you tried creating a middleware class, including the middleware class in the list, and raising MiddlewareNotUsed in the middleware constructor AFTER running the code you propose here?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Actually asking proved to be a good rubber duck. Just after asking, I found the custom database `OPTIONS` one can supply in the `DATABASES` settings like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sql_mode': 'traditional',
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps anyone!

Comment: Haha +1 for answering your own question and ["a good rubber duck"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) :D

Comment: Please provide a link of all available `OPTIONS`

Comment: Here's the mysql page that discusses sql_mode options: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks! Also, relevant link regarding `OPTIONS`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database

Answer (score 17):

You can also try with Adding below option in Database []

```
'OPTIONS': {
        'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
    },
```

Its working.

Comment: I added this, and I still get the warning. Is there any way to tell if it is taking effect properly?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode

Setting sql_mode

> From MySQL 5.7 onwards and on fresh installs of MySQL 5.6, the default
>   value of the sql_mode option contains STRICT_TRANS_TABLES. That option
>   escalates warnings into errors when data are truncated upon insertion,
>   so Django highly recommends activating a strict mode for MySQL to
>   prevent data loss (either STRICT_TRANS_TABLES or STRICT_ALL_TABLES).
>
> If you need to customize the SQL mode, you can set the sql_mode
>   variable like other MySQL options: either in a config file or with the
>   entry 'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'" in the
>   OPTIONS part of your database configuration in DATABASES.

Comment: It is unclear from that text whether sql_mode should be set in `settings.py` or in `my.cnf`.

Comment: It's quite clear in the documentation:"If you need to customize the SQL mode, you can set the sql_mode variable like other MySQL options: either in a config file or with the entry 'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'" in the OPTIONS part of your database configuration in DATABASES."

Answer (score -1):

If you need to union the `queryset`, you can use python chain inster than union.

```
from itertools import chain

gobj_list = user.groups.all()

robj_list = [obj.roles.all() for obj in gobj_list]

ret_list = chain(*robj_list)
```